# Low sugar diets

Tags: weight-loss, diet, bellyfat, carbohydrate, sugar

One thing I've never been good at is eating very healthily, but I work out a lot, cycling 15 miles a day and circuit training or weights most evenings. However, I'm struggling to lose that last bit of fat around my abdomen, which is really bugging me seeing as I do so much exercise. I'm assuming this is coming vastly from my diet. Looking more closely at it, I'm eating a lot more sugar than I should. I need to eat carbs a lot because I'm a rower, and they are critical fuel for the sport. But when I'm at work, I don't get time to make proper lunches, so always end up eating crappy food that I know isn't particularly good for me. Can anyone recommend any quick things that I can pick up from the supermarket, that I don't have to cook, that can help me reduce the amount of sugar in my diet?

Comment: You could try to cook vast amounts of food (with healthy carbs) in the evening and store that for the next few days. That would probably be better than picking the least terrible food from the super market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 0% or 2% Fage Greek Yogurt.
- Grilled chicken.
- Steamed/baked veggies.
- Whey, water, and a blender bottle.
- Tuna fish, just you, the can, and the fork.

There's really no easy way to have very low body fat. For me anyway, when I start getting near 10%, my willpower goes out the window. But I also don't care that much and 10-15% is fine for me. It's just not worth it (to me) to shave those remaining pounds off knowing what I'd have to give up.

If you find someone with a lot of muscle mass that's sub 10%, you'll find someone who's done **a lot** of lifestyle modifications to make that work. It's a bit age and individual dependent as well.

Consider looking into a keto diet (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketogenic_diet). Long term it's the most successful dietary habit I know of.